# How to count user input in python

Tags: python, input

So I want to get the user to input a list of numbers `(1 or 2 digits ex 2,34,4,35,36)` and for python to send back how much total numbers there is  but the problem is python counts each number as a unit when I want it to know the difference between `2` and `34` for example. Idk my brain isn't braining.

Initially , I tried the `len` function then I cam here where I saw the count function but even then it still doesn't work

```
i = input("enter a list")
count(i)
```

(count isnt even recognized? for some reason)

I decided to go back to `len` and I did this

```
i = input ("enter a list")
print ( len(i) )
```

It did work but it counts every single number separately it even counts the commas!!!

I put the list  `34,34,34,35` and I got `11` and I wanted to get `4` because that how much numbers there is

Thank you for talking the time to read my ranting

Comment: You need to [split](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) the string on commas to get a list

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to do spaces, instead of commas. This way, you can use the built in python .split() method which will split a string into a list.

For example, the following code has the following output. (Yours uses a input though, but since inputs are strings anyways, I just created a variable with a string since that is same variable type as inputs.

```
text = "34 35 36 37"
text = text.split()
print(text)
print(len(text))
```

That produces the output of:

```
['34', '35', '36', '37']
4
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do `i = (input("enter a list").count(",")) + 1`

This counts the number of commas, and adds one since the last number will not have a comma.

Like the commenter said above, if you want a list of it separated by commas, you can do

```
i = input("enter a list").split(',')
print(len(i))
```

Answer (score 0):

The variable `i` is a string, therefore when you use `len()` it will count all the characters. To count the numbers separated by commas you can use the `split` function.

```
 i = input("enter a list")  #  34,34,34,35
 print(len(i.split(",")))
```